# Story of "/" and "\" in different OS

Tags: windows, linux, macos, unix, operating-system

I am confused with "/" and "\" and "//" in different OS. Linux and Unix use "/" , Windows use "\" but Windows can understand "/" and if we want to use windows style address in programming we must use "\" . I am really confused with these cases.
please help me.
thanks

Comment: Just history, I think. CP/M uses backslashes and Windows evolved from that IIRC.

Comment: Maybe they used a `|` and waited to see in which direction it falls.

Comment: History question or mind ambiguity question ?

Answer (score 5):

Historically, `/` was the character in UNIX, in the 1970s. At some time, in the early 1980s, there came a guy who wrote MS-DOS, which was quite similiar to CP/M, and these both used the `/` for command options. When MS-DOS got directories in 2.0, there had to be found an alternative and that was the `\`. Since then there is this difference.

Internally the DOS kernel supported the `/`, nevertheless. And so did Windows.

Answer (score 2):

as always, wikipedia to the rescue http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backslash

[Why is the DOS path character "\"?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2005/06/24/432386.aspx)

[HOW ASCII GOT ITS BACKSLASH](http://www.bobbemer.com/BACSLASH.HTM)

Comment: Very nice - especially the historical stuff abut the backslash. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Wiki may help you : see  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29

this wiki page explains all existing way to use "/" and "\" then it may helps to remove mind ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what to tell you about the "/" and "\" you can read that on [wikipedia link here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29). However when programming do not hardcode paths , ther is usually a library that handles paths like for example Server.MapPath in ASP.net, using such a library ensures that your application(if it's cross platform), will get the correct path regarding what delimitator it is using